# Powershell connectivity to SQL server and count extract

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch count of table from SQL server by connecting using Powershell, but I am getting the below error message, but if I just do select on the table instead of count then the same code is returning results, please suggest as I am not getting a solution to this problem.

Error Message:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Execution Timeout
>   Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding."
>   +     $DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Script:

```
  [string] $Server= "Server_nm"
  [string] $Database = "DB_nm"
  [string] $UserSqlQuery = $("SELECT count(1) AS cnt FROM [tbl]")


##$resultsDatatable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery 

function GenericSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
$Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery

$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $Command
$Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
$Connection.Close()

return $Dataset.Tables[0]
} $resultsDatatable = GenericSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery
#validate we got data

Write-Host ("The table contains: " + $resultsDatatable.Rows.Count + " rows")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet) function instead.

```
# initialize Variables
 [string] $Server= "Server_nm"
 [string] $Database = "DB_nm"
 [string] $UserSqlQuery = $("SELECT count(1) AS cnt FROM [tbl]")

# Invoke-SqlCmd
 $resultsDatatable = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $UserSqlQuery

# validate we got data
 Write-Host ("The table contains: " + $resultsDatatable.cnt + " rows")
```